# MYSQL query that returns a default row if no other row is matched

Tags: mysql, sql

I have an example table "cities" like this:

```
id   |   city
----------------
1      London
2      Liverpool
3      Birmingham
4      (Other)
```

Can I write a query that returns `(Other)` if I provide a non-existing city... such as:

```
SELECT * FROM cities WHERE city = "London"      --> {1, London}
SELECT * FROM cities WHERE city = "Manchester"  --> {4, (Other) }
```

I understand that the second SELECT-statement will return nothing. But how can I modify it to return the "(Other)" row? Conceptual code:

```
SELECT * FROM cities WHERE city = "Manchester" OTHERWISE WHERE city = "(Other)"
```

Comment: Self LEFT JOIN the tables.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One method is:

```
select c.*
from cities c
where c.city in (?, '(Other)')
order by c.city = '(Other)'
limit 1;
```

This retrieves the two rows possible rows that might match (`?` is a placeholder for the name you want).  If there are two rows, then then one that is not "other" is chosen.

Answer (score 2):

Consider:

```
select * 
from cities 
where 
    city = 'Manchester'
    or (city = '(Other)' and not exists (select 1 from cities where city = 'Manchester'))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select DISTINCT 'Other' AS city
FROM cities WHERE NOT EXISTS (select * from cities where city = 'Brisbane')
UNION ALL
SELECT city from cities where city = 'Brisbane'
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `self join` with a slight twist

```
select a.id, a.city
from (select *, city = '(Other)' as other from cities)  a
left join cities b on b.city = 'London'
where a.city = b.city or (b.city is null and a.other = 1)
```

[**Demo**](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/rsN72n2mWahMctM9Re9QFA/1)